# How to combine vector data (census) with raster data (inundation)

Tags: qgis, raster, vector, flood

I am hoping to find a way to create a map showing the overlap of flood inundation and social vulnerability in QGIS.

I tried using zonal statistics, but it does not take into account the values, just areas of intersection.

Is there a way to do a statistical analysis which takes into account the field data within QGIS or is this something I would have to do in R/Python?

Comment: Welcome to GIS SE. You need to ask for one problem in one question. Limit your question to either qgis or coding.

Comment: It depends what you want to calculate and how your data are structured. If your flood data are continuous then it is likely a good idea to rasterize your social vulnerability layer and work with the raster calculator.  If your flood data are categorical, and not too large, you could vectorise your flood data and perform an intersection/overlap analysis. By providing some more information you will more likely get a useful answer.